# How to delete all words that begin with another complete word

Tags: bash

I need to go through a dictionary and delete all words that begin with another complete word--"attic", for example, begins with the word "at", so I want to delete it. I wrote a bash script that works:

```
while read p; do
    sed -i "/^$p./d" words.txt.tmp
done < words.txt.tmp
```

But after a minute it's still on the A's and that's not good. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -v` to filter out patterns. And you can use process substitution to put `^` at the beginning of each word in the word list and use that as the pattern file.

```
grep -v -f <(sed 's/.*/^&./' words.txt.tmp) words.txt.tmp > words.txt.filtered
```